# Android: what is the simplest way to mask a shape onto a View?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, fragment

I would like to create a circular map fragment view

```
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:transitionName="@string/map"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        tools:context="com.example.gyang.android.MapActivity"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Currently my fragment is a big square. What is the easiest way to turn this into a circle?

Answer (score 0):

For me simplest to make middle transparent shape was by constructing outside part with views: topBox, rightBox, bottomBox, leftBox and leaving middle as blank.
I also needed to have rounded corners, for this I used SVG images to simulate corners of transparent middle shape.

[image]